# Unable to see view page when click page link in Drupal admin views created list section?

Tags: views, theming

I have created a `view` both `page` and `block` both are working in with out admin login section in my home page but after login when I click page link not getting view list page.

Please find below screen-shot make sure path module is enabled.is there any plugin missing?
[image]

Please help me.

Thanks,
Parvateesam.

Comment: What does it gives you 404? 403? When you say you are not getting view liste page what do you mean? Put an export of the views if does not have any external module views

Comment: Hi  Gianni Di Falco ,Thanks for your quick replay ,issue resolved due to themes override happen this issue.just i have disabled unnecessary theme.it's working fine.